# number of items in bootsrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using a bootstrap navbar which contains 3 elements.
I want it to be distributed across the whole navbar, but it doesn't.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="navbar steps" style="position:relative;z-index:7">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="row-fluid nav nav-pills">
            <li class="span3 active">
                <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="step active">
                    <span class="number">1</span>
                    <span class="desc"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Source</span>   
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="span3">
                <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="step">
                    <span class="number">2</span>
                    <span class="desc"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Détail</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="span3">
                <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" class="step">
                    <span class="number">3</span>
                    <span class="desc"><i class="icon-cog"></i> Configuration</span>
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using ?

Comment: Check out this example http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/justified-nav.html

Comment: @DavidNguyen no I already tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: @Sachin I am currently using 2.2.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bootstrap grids](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) are built off a 12 column layout.  If you want three items to take up the whole width, use `span4` (=12/**3**).

Try changing `span3` to `span4`.

### [Here's a Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/XXVXH/)

#### Which should look like this:

[image: screenshot]

#### Code:

```html
<div class="navbar steps" style="position:relative;z-index:7">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="row-fluid nav nav-pills">
            <li class="span4 active">
                <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="step active">
                    <span class="number">1</span>
                    <span class="desc">
                        <i class="icon-ok"></i>
                        Source
                    </span>   
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="span4">
                <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="step">
                    <span class="number">2</span>
                    <span class="desc">
                        <i class="icon-ok"></i>
                        Détail
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="span4">
                <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" class="step">
                    <span class="number">3</span>
                    <span class="desc">
                        <i class="icon-cog"></i>
                        Configuration
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

## Option 2

As fasouto pointed out, you can also try using a [justified navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/justified-nav.html).

### [Here's a Justified Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/XXVXH/1/)